# Why is no work done by magnetic forces in a uniform B and E field (perpendicular to one another)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work

Say $B$ points in the $x$ direction, and $E$ points in the $z$ direction.  Assuming a charged particle begins at rest at the origin, its motion will be a cycloid that progresses indefinitely in the $y$ direction.

Assuming that the magnetic force never does work, how do you explain the change in electric potential energy as the particle oscillates in the $z$ direction?  How do you account for the particles motion in the $y$ direction when there is no potential defined in that direction?

My only guess is that (and I have not yet studied this) the $B$ field is equivalent to the $E$ field when relative motion is considered, so perhaps there is a reference frame (could be inertial or non-inertial) where this situation is can be "transformed" to one in which there is only an $E$ field (may or may not be constant) and no $B$ field.

Comment: Something I'm confused about in your question: what exactly needs to be explained about the change in electric potential energy? In other words, why would you think it shouldn't change?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this situation is similar to that of a swinging pendulum, except the gravitational force is "replaced" by the electric force, and the tension force which confines the motion of the pendulum bob is "replaced" by the magnetic force.

I thought that systems have a tendency to reduce potential energy, and the fact that the existence of the B field causes the particle to periodically gain potential energy makes it appear as though the B force does work against the E field, but I guess that's false since the B force is always perpendicular to the motion.

Comment: i thought you may mean this: A varying magnetic field generates an electric field, and an electric field can do work on a particle. This is called Faraday's law of induction:

∇×E⃗ =−∂B⃗ ∂t